# How to paint this bottle glossy?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, painting, sketching, digital, highlights

I am trying to paint this self designed thermos bottle glossy red but I am not been able to understand the light and how to give the glossy effect and how to give light effect on the division line in between bottle.

[image]

Also after disabling the outline layer it looks weird, I even used pen tool to give proper shape but the outline looks crooked. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will cheat and give you some links for you to study.

[Inkscape: realistic lighting and shading](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/inkscape-realistic-lighting-and-shading/90478#90478)

[How can I make a shape look like it is made of glass?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51538/how-can-i-make-a-shape-look-like-it-is-made-of-glass/51557#51557)

[Prototype Visualization: How can I learn to render glass convincingly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly/77256#77256)

What you will notice and learn is that a glossy material has its looks for what is **what they are reflecting**, not what the material is made of.

And here is an example applied. In that post you will see how "glossy" means reflection.

[Creating an implied floor with light](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/creating-an-implied-floor-with-light/63851#63851)

And let's get into your image.

I just added some random shapes with a gradient fill inside and transparency.

They try to show what was the light's shape and where it was when you took the image.

[image]

Here you can see the shapes.

[image]

Here I am playing with some gradients.

On the first image, I have a gradient similar to your image.

[image]

But see what happen if I start playing with the relationship between the light and dark zones.

Here I added more white. Not it is not only a gradient, it has a big source of light illuminating it.

[image]

If I bring closer a dark gray, I am saying " the white is a light source reflected with a dark surrounding. My surface is glossy.

The closer this contrast is, the glossier it becomes. In 3D material design, this is called the roughness of the glossy material.

[image]

This is a "spike" in the shading, in the gradient. It can be used for example to make human skin look metallic.

[image]

Take a look here.

[Things to consider when creating realistic highlights and dark reflections on metallic surfaces](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50918/things-to-consider-when-creating-realistic-highlights-and-dark-reflections-on-me/50925#50925)

Comment: really appreciate your answer , helped me a lot