# How do I recreate the type part of this image in illustator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, 3d

[image]I want to customize my own text.  It requires curved text, maybe on a sphere and with 3d effect. Any tutorials out there i can follow?

Comment: Which applications do you use and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome Bertha! I'm sure there are tutorials out there. What have you found? Have you searched?

Comment: Illustrator is not the right tool to do this. It can be done, yes. Is it the right tool, no. Use a 3D software like Blender.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to map a symbol containing text to a cylinder using a 3D Extrude and Bevel effect, at least as a starting point.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept non-photorealistic appearance without glossy beveled edges you can make text as bent along a cylindrical surface with envelope distortion. If it must have at the same time extruded thickness you can get it with blending:

[image]

1. A text and an elliptical arc duplicated + joined (=2 x Ctrl+J)
2. The joined arcs are brought to front, select all, apply Object > Envelope Distortion > Make with Top Object

Making the extrusion:

3. Make a duplicate, change its fill color (it's black here, any color other than the original can be used).
   You have in the options panel a possibility to edit the envelope or the content. Select Edit Contents to change the fill color. Press Esc when ready.
4. Send the recolored version to back and shrink it horizontally. Move it behind the original color version.
5. Blend the versions. Either have continuous color or specified steps (say 20 or more) blend option.

Without blending the scaled differently colored version (preferably grey or black) can also be used as a drop shadow. It's tried later on a sphere.

Bevels cannot be inserted easily and there's no hope to get photorealistic metallic appearance in this way. Any simple gradient coloring doesn't make it especially well although it works with blending. You cannot color the extruded surface which is actually a bunch of a little moved 2D shapes.

If the surface must be spherical you can make it by combining pieces of ellipses. The circle is needed to draw the ellipses:

[image]

It's not a must to split and join curves. The piece in the middle is made with the Shape Builder which can also be used to kill the unnecessary parts by pressing Alt key.

Extrusion nor simulating it by blending is not the only way to make some apparent thickness. You can as well insert a drop shadow. It's in spherical case a dark  copy which is scaled smaller, not only shifted like in a plane:

[image]

The background here is the original circle filled with a radial gradient. To get the same shading to the the text you can use blending mode multiply (not so good if the background is dark) or have gradient coloring. You must expand the envelope distortion and convert the text to a compound path to be able to color the text as a single object without diving into direct editing mode inside the envelope.

In the next image there's a drop shadow and the text has radial gradient color:

[image]

Metallic gloss is complex. You must create fake environment reflections Complex gradients can be used. Search for chrome and gold effect tutorials. This older case can also give some idea: [How to make an object black and metallic?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142569/how-to-make-an-object-black-and-metallic)

You can find more examples in GDSE.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about leaving illustrator to use a 3D software. I’m going to try Blender as suggested above.